# single file page model aspx.net program: newbie program

Tags: asp.net

Thank you for your very precise answers.  I tried them.  Still nothing happens.
Note that I put writes to the "response" and "trace" I do not see anything in the 
logs that GoDaddy provides:

```
<%@Page language="vb" Debug="true"%>
<script language="vb" runat="server">
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal Sender as Object, _
ByVal e as System.EventArgs)
dim sum as integer
dim input as integer
response.write("RW")
trace.write("TW")

If not ViewState("nnn") is nothing then
sum = ViewState("nnn")
end if
input = txtInput.text
sum = sum + input

ViewState("sum") = sum
txtsum.text = sum

end sub
</script>
<html>
<body>
<form id="form" runat="server">
<p>Input:<asp:TextBox ID="txtinput" runat="server" maxlength="10" enabled="true"/></p>
<p>Sum:<asp:TextBox ID="txtsum" runat="server" maxlength="10" enabled="true"/></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Add Em" onClick="Button1_Click" runat="server"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Intermittantly, I get an error message from the server:

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed.  If an application is hosted by a WEb Farm or cluster, ensure that
<machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm.
AutoGenerate cannot be used in acluster.

S  ee http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?lLinkID=314055 for more information
```

I spoke to godaddy technical support;  As they cannot reproduce the problemn, they
cannot help me.

P. S., Thank you, banana, for your concern about my putting phone and conventional mail 
contacts information on this web site,  Often,
I do this in posts to forums such as StackOverflow
and Usenet News.  I have never had a response by these older communications
methods, wanted or otherwise.

Comment: a valid html markup would be a start. + never leave personal details in a question, you dont want several million potential calls on a daily basis.

Comment: have a look [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input button has to be runat="server" as well in order for this to work.

Comment: Also, since this is asp.net, rather than classic asp, the server script and Page should have `language="vb"`, instead of `language="vbscript"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@Page language="vb" Debug="true"%>
<script language="vb" runat="server">
  Protected Sub x(ByVal Sender as Object, _
   ByVal e as System.EventArgs)
dim sum as integer
dim input as integer
response.write("RW")
trace.write("TW")

If not ViewState("sum") is nothing then
  sum = ViewState("sum")
end if
input = txtInput.text
sum = sum + input

ViewState("sum") = sum
txtsum.text = sum

end sub
</script>
<html>
<body>
<form id="form" runat="server">
<p>Input:<asp:TextBox ID="txtinput" runat="server" maxlength="10" enabled="true"/></p>
<p>Sum:<asp:TextBox ID="txtsum" runat="server" maxlength="10" enabled="true"/></p>
<p><asp:button  Text="Add Em!!"  onClick="x" runat="server"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I needed to use "asp:button" rather than "input type=submit"  Thanks to everyone.